# ReactJS - removing parent node and memory cleanup

Tags: reactjs

What happens when you delete a Dom node that a ReactJs component is rendered into using a library such as query? Will the React code (and virtual DOM) running in memory know to clean itself up?

The React Component

```
var Box = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
       return (
          <div>
             Hello, world! I am a Box.
          </div>
       );
    }
});

React.render(<Box/>, document.getElementById('content'));
```

and then use Jquery later with

```
$("#content").remove();
```

I found this function, however the React component is a 3rd party component and React is bundled up so I do not have access to it.

```
React.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('content'));
```

Comment: What do you mean you don't have access to it? If you included React as a script tag, it's in global scope, therefore you should have access to it. Regarding the clean up question, from my experience, React won't clean itself up if you just remove the contents of a DOM node using jQuery. Instead you have to use the method you mentioned. Although, keep in mind it's in [ReactDOM package](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#unmountcomponentatnode) now.